# Is there any java library for Wavelet transformation using Haat as mother wavley?

Tags: haar-wavelet

Hi am developing an application which is use wavelet transformation for feature extraction.
I am not able to translate 2d Discrete wavelets Transformation for with haar transformation . I need a source code to do it. Is there any java library already available to do this . Please give me detail about this.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, it's in java.Check if your wavelet is there https://code.google.com/p/jwave/